# How to get ViewChild from content inside the cdkPortal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have several components that bring "tools" with them and on creation insert those tools into predefined "named" places in the app, like left/right/side toolbars. They do it with Angular CDK Portals.
It looks like this:

```
// component template here...

// then portions of UI for portals, like this:
<ng-template cdkPortal #leftToolbar>
    <app-search-input #search (search)="onSearch($event)"></app-search-input>
</ng-template>
```

My goal is to somehow get the reference to `app-search-input` component placed inside the portal.

Shown below doesn't work, `this.searchEl` is always `undefined`:

```
// component class
@ViewChild('search', {static: true}) searchEl: SearchInputComponent;
```

Any thoughts, guys?

Comment: @yurzui works great, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

You're not able to access to any content from `ng-template` till it has been rendered.

But you can always subscribe to the event when your ViewChild is being initialized through setter:

```
@ViewChild('search') set searchEl(value: any) {
  if (value) {
    // do smth
  }
};
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etmb3g?file=src/app/cdk-portal-overview-example.html)**